# hover on a td and add a class to span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, row

***Question:*** I want to hover my mouse on a row and again in that particular row, if I hover my mouse on `icons`(`pencil`, `trash`), then the corresponding icons should get rounded borders as shown in first snapshot..

Can you please help me how can I achieve this ? I want everthing to be controlled using JS/jquery actions. Appreciate your help

**Explanation: so far what i did and my code..**

**1)**  Below is my `td` element, Now on mouseover the css class `icon-hover`(below code pasted) should get appended to the `span` class below

```
<td class='j-td-edit font-color-meta'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
```

[image]

CSS snippet responsible to get the rounded border is below

```
/*icon hover style*/
.icon-hover {
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    padding: 0.4vw;
    border-radius: 0.3vw;
}
```

---

**2)**  When I hover my mouse on a row, the row gets highlighted with below code and screenshot attached..

```
/*row hover*/
.hover-color{
    background-color: #D0CFCF;
}
```

=> corresponding JS action for `"mouseenter, mouseleave"` and image are below

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.row', function () {
    var $this = $(this), row = $this.closest("tr");
    row.addClass("hover-color");
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.row', function () {
    var $this = $(this), row = $this.closest("tr");
    row.removeClass("hover-color");
});
```

[image]

Comment: You seem to know how to make things happen when hovering over the entire row, so why don't you try doing the same with the icons?

Comment: after i hover on a row, i need to again check for another level hover on the icons. that part is what I am finding it tricky..

Comment: @Jeto, I can't believe I did it...  I was bumping my head for 30 mins to fix this.. and your small piece of idea enlightened me..

Comment: Haha, no problem, happy you solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS `:hover` pseudo-class

```css
.row {
  height: 35px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
.row:hover {
  background: #dddddd;
}

.row .glyphicon {
  padding: 5px;
}
.row .glyphicon:hover {
  outline: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<table width="100%">
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Test</td>
    <td class='j-td-edit font-color-meta'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Test</td>
    <td class='j-td-edit font-color-meta'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Test</td>
    <td class='j-td-edit font-color-meta'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No problem @gopigorantala , always glad to help

Answer (score 0):

After @jeto words... I found the solution of my code..

```
//below snippet find the nth(which is 4th td in my case and appends the class below.
 $(this).find('td').eq(4).find('span').addClass('icon-hover'));
```

and

```
$(this).find('td').eq(4).find('span').removeClass('icon-hover'));
```